# Can't find user's credentials in express using passport

Tags: node.js, express, facebook-authentication, passport.js

I am facing a weird issue, my app is logged in using user's fb credentials but I cant get to see his email, name or id etc. Here is what I am doing in my users.js route :-

```
router.get('/auth/facebook',passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email', 'user_friends']}));

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',

passport.authenticate('facebook',{ successRedirect:'/profile',failureRedirect:'/'},function(req,res){
console.log("in passport req");      //doesn't get printed  
console.log(req);
}));
```

And in my config/passport.js I am doing :-

```
var configAuth=require('./auth');  //holds all appID, secret and successurl
var FacebookStrategy=require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

var passport=require('passport');

module.exports=function(passport){

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
console.log("the user's credentials are:  ");   //doesn't get printed
console.log(profile.user);
}
));

};
```

And everything is working fine I am being redirected to successURL but how can I get the user info cause without it everything is in vain, any help will be appreciated. There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check req.user

```
app.get('login',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { 
    failureRedirect:'/'
   }),
 function(req, res, next){
  //check req.user   
  console.log('user should be',req.user);
  res.redirect('/profile')
 });
```

Comment: happy coding asim